# SQLite gives me a no such column error, with the column being the value of a variable I'm trying to store into the table

Tags: php, sqlite

When I run the following query, SQLite tells me that there is no such column "test", where "test" is the value in the variable $entryname. I want to store $entryname into the name column, not 'name' into $entryname. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO files (name, description, filename) VALUES (' . $entryname . ', ' . $entrydescription . ', ' . $filename . ')';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your *string* values. They are getting interpreted as a SQLite variable otherwise.

Try the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO files (name, description, filename) VALUES ('" . $entryname . "', '" . $entrydescription . "', '" . $filename . "')";
```

You should also look into preventing [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).